# Node position in TreeView

Tags: java, javafx

How can I get the position of a node from a TreeView with onclick event in JavaFX?

[image: JavaFX scene]

Let's say when I click on the node (dolor sit amet,) selected with the black circle how can I get the position?

I have tried this with an event when a node is expanded:

```
root.addEventHandler(EventType.ROOT, (Event event) -> {
        if (event.getEventType().getName().equals("BranchExpandedEvent")) {
            TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.getSource();
            //here I want to know item position
        }
    });
```

Comment: there is no item position, there's a cell position that has the item - please read a basic tutorial to learn how to implement and configure custom TreeCells

Comment: What do you want to do with the position(x,y) ? be specific.

Comment: @Calips I want to have this position and to add some other Nodes (Vertical line in my case to connect the treeitems at the same level) in the TreeView.

Comment: @kleopatra Can you give me some suggestion about that. To let you know I have done some of my CustomCell that extend TreeCell using the HBox widget, not so much success to achieve something out of the TreeItems so a Vertical Line that goes on top of them which should not be connected with TreeItems but only with the TreeView.

Answer (score 1):

The `Node` you're talking about is known as the [`disclosureNode`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html#disclosureNodeProperty) and is accessible via the `TreeCell`.

> The disclosure node is commonly seen represented as a triangle that rotates on screen to indicate whether or not the TreeItem that it is placed beside is expanded or collapsed.

You can get the position of this `Node` with properties such as [`Node.boundsInLocal`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInLocalProperty()) or [`Node.boundsInParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty()). There are also methods in `Node` to help convert between coordinate spaces (e.g. [`localToScene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene(javafx.geometry.Bounds)), [`sceneToLocal`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#sceneToLocal(javafx.geometry.Bounds)), etc...).

---

Also, the following code is suspect:

```
root.addEventHandler(EventType.ROOT, (Event event) -> {
    if (event.getEventType().getName().equals("BranchExpandedEvent")) {
    }
});
```

You shouldn't need to check the name of the `EventType`. Instead, register the `EventHandler` for the `EventType` you want to listen for—in this case, [`TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#branchExpandedEvent()). For example, if your `TreeItem`s have values of type `String`:

```
// "root" is a TreeItem<String>
// "event" is a TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<String>
root.addEventHandler(TreeItem.<String>branchExpandedEvent(), event -> {
    // do something...
});
```

If you must check the `EventType` inside the `EventHandler` then test that the `EventType`s are equal, not their names; it's less error-prone.

```
root.addEventHandler(Event.ANY, event -> {
    if (event.getEventType().equals(TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent()) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

---

> I want to have this position and to add some other Nodes (Vertical line in my case to connect the treeitems at the same level) in the TreeView.

I haven't looked into it, but this sounds like it should be implemented by the `TreeCell`. The `TreeItem` shouldn't know much, if anything, about the view. In other words, handling this inside an event handler added to the root `TreeItem` seems like the wrong place. Note, you can get the expanded status of a `TreeItem` from within a `TreeCell` as it has access to its `TreeItem`.

Comment: I have problems accessing the TreeCell from the TreeItem. In the event, I can get easily the TreeItem `TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.getSource();`. How to access the TreeCell in order to access the disclosureNode and to use the properties of it.

Comment: You likely can't from the `TreeItem`. You can use your own `TreeCell` implementation by setting the `TreeView.cellFactory` property. You may need to subclass [`TreeCellSkin`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TreeCellSkin.html) as well.